# Angular 17 running in SSR mode cannot find Web Worker script

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, vite, web-worker

I have an Angular 17 web application running with SSR enabled. When I run the application with `ng serve` I get the following error (terminal and a popup on the web UI).

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./assets/js/worker.js" from "/index.html?html-proxy&index=0.js". Does the file exist?
/index.html:2:31
1  |  
2  |      import { asyncRun } from './assets/js/worker.js';
   |                                ^
3  |      window.__worker__ = { asyncRun };
4  |
```

My `index.html` is pretty standard and the section relevant to the error looks like the following.

```
<script type="module">
  import { asyncRun } from './assets/js/worker.js';
  window.__worker__ = { asyncRun };
</script>
```

I understand that starting with Angular 17, they are using Vite (as opposed to Angular 16, they were using Webpack by default). When I try the same approach in an Angular 16 application, I don't see this error.

Anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: `window` isn't available during SSR

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

Angular has it own way of handling web workers, you can read it in the docs: [anuglar-web-workers](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker)

I followed the instructions and got the web worker running pretty easily, also note, that the script you provided is a bit confusing, there is no `onSuccess` method, but we can use this to leverage the web worker functionality!

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  const message = `hello, world ${new Date()}`;
  self.postMessage({ message });
});
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t3un9o?file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.worker.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fassets%2Fworker.js,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fassets%2FwebWorker.js&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.worker.ts) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start` -> `check the console for web worker output!`

---

Could you create a separate script file called `workerRunner.js` and move the contents of the script tag inside that and place it on the assets folder, then in the `angular.json` you can directly run the script using the `scripts` array!

angular.json

```
        ...
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": ["src/assets/webWorker.js"],
        "server": "src/main.server.ts",
        "prerender": true,
        ...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i97bhp?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Findex.html,test%2Fangular.json,test%2Fsrc%2Fassets%2FwebWorker.js&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: Your example here is not clear (also on Stackblitz where is webWorker.js?). My script is already in the assets folder (eg assets/js). If i explicitly include it as you stated in angular.json, I still get the same error.

Comment: @JaneWayne please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated and the web worker , because I need error to check the issue

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uyguxn?file=test%2Fsrc%2Findex.html